# CMake, SDL on Mac OS X, "can't find -lSDLmain"

Tags: cmake, sdl

Following the instructions [here](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL%3aTutorials%3aSetup#CMake), I've set up a `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
Find_Package (SDL REQUIRED)
Find_Package (SDL_image REQUIRED)

link_libraries (
     ${SDL_LIBRARY}
     ${SDLIMAGE_LIBRARY}
     SDLmain
)
```

When running `cmake`, I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lSDLmain
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/GameOfLife] Error 1
```

Running `g++` by hand gives the same error:

```
$ g++-4.7 -std=c++0x ../src/*.cpp -lSDLmain          
ld: library not found for -lSDLmain
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is directly programming related, well within the scope outlined by the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It's a problem that took me a while to work out, and there is no online solution that I could easily find. Self-answering the question is [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). A comment explaining the downvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` doesn't know where to find `SDLmain`; I need to link to the directory using `link_directory` in `CMakeLists.txt.

---

Running

```
$ g++-4.7 -std=c++0x ../src/*.cpp `sdl-config --libs`
```

works fine, so I've clearly got SDL installed correctly. Checking the output of `sdl-config --libs`:

```
$ sdl-config --libs  
-L/opt/local/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -Wl,-framework,Cocoa
```

So the thing that's *not* in the `CMakeLists.txt` is the `-L/opt/local/lib`. That should be added into the `CMakeLists.txt` using `link_directory`:

```
link_directories( /opt/local/lib )
```

And then `cmake` runs fine.